# Sending push notifications to Notification Hub via Node.js used new sdk

Tags: azure-notificationhub, azure-sdk-js

I've found [this how-to guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/notification-hubs/notification-hubs-nodejs-push-notification-tutorial) on sending push notifications with in a Node.js application, however, it seems to be using the now unsupported `azure-sdk-for-node` [sdk](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-node). The new recommended javascript (`azure-sdk-for-js`) sdk is found [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-js), however, I'm finding it difficult to map the functionality described in the tutorial to the new sdk. Specifically, the new repository makes no mentioned of a `NotificationServiceHub`, nor the `createNotificationHubService` method. I've found `@azure/arm-notificationhubs`, but this seems to be for managing purposes only.

Is it possible to send push notifications via the new javascript sdk?

Answer (score 0):

You can [migration from Node.js packages (azure-sdk-for-node) to JavaScript packages (azure-sdk-for-js).](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-js/blob/master/documentation/Migration.md)

[image]

**So it's possible to send push notifications via the new javascript sdk.**

Comment: Right, I did see this. In the old sdk, the notification hub service was under the `azure-sb` module (service bus) and the new sdk `@azure/service-bus` does not support this functionality. I actually found this issue, which unfortunately confirms what I found: https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-js/issues/3009